# wrapper.find is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enzyme, jestjs

I am trying test a component in React w/ TypeScript using Jest and Enzyme.

My test is as follows:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import * as sinon from 'sinon';

import { ButtonGroup } from '../../../src/components';

describe('.ButtonGroup', () => {
  it('should render', () => {
    const { wrapper } = setup({});
    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);
  });

  it('should call the rightHandler handler on click', () => {
    const onClickHandler = sinon.spy();
    const wrapper = setup({ rightHandler: onClickHandler });
    wrapper.find('a').simulate('click');
    expect(onClickHandler).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
const setup = propOverrides => {
  const props = Object.assign({ leftBtn: MOCK_LEFT, rightBtn: MOCK_RIGHT }, propOverrides);
  const wrapper = shallow(<ButtonGroup {...props} />);
  return { wrapper };
};

const MOCK_LEFT = { type: 'reset', className: 'is-light', value: 'Reset' };
const MOCK_RIGHT = { type: 'button', className: 'is-primary', value: 'Search' };
```

However I am getting an error: `TypeError: wrapper.find is not a function`

The component I am testing looks like

```
import * as React from 'react';

const ButtonGroup = ({ leftBtn, rightBtn, leftHandler = null, rightHandler = null }) => (
  <div className="field is-grouped is-grouped-right">
    <p className="control">
      <input type={leftBtn.type} className={'button ' + leftBtn.className} value={leftBtn.value} onClick={leftHandler} />
    </p>
    <p className="control">
      <input type={rightBtn.type} className={'button ' + rightBtn.className} value={rightBtn.value} onClick={rightHandler} />
    </p>
  </div>
);

export default ButtonGroup;
```

I would like to essentially asset that on click, the action I expect is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
const setup = propOverrides => {
  const props = Object.assign({ leftBtn: MOCK_LEFT, rightBtn: MOCK_RIGHT }, propOverrides);
  const wrapper = shallow(<ButtonGroup {...props} />);
  return wrapper;
};
```

Doing `return { wrapper }` is the same as `return { wrapper: wrapper }` so it's not your DOM element anymore, but an object with a property `wrapper` containing your DOM element.

This is a [small bin](https://jsbin.com/lonujetahu/edit?html,js,console) to illustrate the issue.

Comment: Thank you, I had missed deconstructing setup() in my it() block